# getSupportFragmentManager() crashes app after user cancels a SENDTO chooser (but not if e-mail app is opened)

Tags: android, fragment

I use a fairly simple method to send e-mail from an `OnClickListener` linked to a view:

```
TextView emailAddr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmailAddr);
emailAddr.setOnClickListener(emailClick);
```

In the same activity I have an `OnClickListener`:

```
final OnClickListener emailClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
                Uri.parse("dearjohn@acme.com"));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.contactsEMailSubject));
            startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**NOTE:** *I also had this setup with an anonymous Listener with the exact same results.*

With no default e-mail app the user will see a chooser window.  If they continue to send e-mail everything is fine, if not and they cancel the chooser dialog my app crashes.

I traced the problem to an attempt to display a progress dialog in my `refreshData()` method (which is called from `onResume()`).

My progressDialog code looks like this: (maybe I am missing something here thta means I cannot re-use it under certain circumstances?)

```
public class HttpProgressDlg extends DialogFragment 
    implements OnCancelListener, OnDismissListener {

    interface HttpProgressDlgCancelListener {
        void onCancelHttpProgressDlg();
    }

    public HttpProgressDlg() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedinstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.http_progress, container);
        getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.dlgProgressTitle));
        getDialog().setOnCancelListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        HttpProgressDlgCancelListener activity = (HttpProgressDlgCancelListener) getActivity();
        activity.onCancelHttpProgressDlg();  // tell activity to cancel http request
        this.dismiss();  // "close" the dialog
    }
```

and the code trying to use it:

```
protected void showProgressDialog() {
    FragmentManager fragmentMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    httpProgressDlg = new HttpProgressDlg();
    httpProgressDlg.show(fragmentMgr, "http_progress");
}
```

I thought the problem was that `getSupportFragmentManager()` returns null.  (Yes, I can check for that and I have - more on that later)

What happens when the user cancels the chooser dialog is that Android wants to resume the activity of course.  My trace takes me into 
1. `onSaveInstanceState`  (weird that) which completes ok.
2. `onResume` - which sets a view's text, hides or shows another view, then calls refreshData which calls `showProgressDialog()`.

Unlike every other time the code gets called this time it returns null except if I really drag out the tracing/debugging process in which case it works ok.  Seems like there is some process that makes this return null.

LogCat shows some strange message about having an illegal state after calling `onSavewInstanceState`:

```
08-15 10:49:55.187: D/AndroidRuntime(16016): Shutting down VM
08-15 10:49:55.187: W/dalvikvm(16016): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b682a0)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.viterra.glencoregrain/com.viterra.glencoregrain.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.viterra.glencoregrain.GlencoreBaseActivity.showProgressDialog(GlencoreBaseActivity.java:274)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.viterra.glencoregrain.MainActivity.refreshData(MainActivity.java:113)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.viterra.glencoregrain.GlencoreBaseActivity.onResume(GlencoreBaseActivity.java:103)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at com.viterra.glencoregrain.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:41)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1188)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
08-15 10:49:55.227: E/AndroidRuntime(16016):    ... 10 more
08-15 10:50:09.132: I/Process(16016): Sending signal. PID: 16016 SIG: 9
```

I have now put in place a loop to ensure it does not end until I have a non-null value returned, like so (just for testing understand)

```
FragmentManager fragmentMgr = null;
while (fragmentMgr == null) { 
    fragmentMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
}   
httpProgressDlg = new HttpProgressDlg();
httpProgressDlg.show(fragmentMgr, "http_progress");
```

The code then proceeds to the `httpProgressDlg.show(...)` part where it crashes...
I don't get this at all.  Moving to other activities and back (also using "startActivity(intent..." code does not cause this crash , only when I cancel the Chooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not show dialog fragments manually in `onResume` because Android automatically restores them.